# Decode base64 PDF and write to file in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to decode a pdf from a response and write it to a file.

The file gets created and appears to be the correct file size, but when I go to open it, I get an error that says, "**There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.**"

I am using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840233/jmeter-how-to-extract-values-from-a-response-which-has-been-decoded-from-base6) to decode and create the file.

I set the base64 encoded file returned from the API as the variable `vars.get("documentText")`

Here is how my BeanShell PostProcessor code looks:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String Createresponse= vars.get("documentText");
vars.put("response",new String(Base64.decodeBase64(Createresponse.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

Output = vars.get("response");

f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Test.pdf");
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Output);
f.close();
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

I have also done the following, but get the same result:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(vars.get("documentText"));
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Test.pdf");
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

**EDIT:**

The entire PDF from the **Response** looks like the following: (these are just the first 5 lines (of approx. 7,548 lines), but they are all similar):

```
JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8pCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAo&#xd;
/v8AUQB0ACAANQAuADUALgAxKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTcwMzI3MTgwNTEzKQo+Pgpl&#xd;
bmRvYmoKMiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQg&#xd;
MCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovU0EgdHJ1ZQovU00gMC4wMgovY2EgMS4wCi9DQSAx&#xd;
LjAKL0FJUyBmYWxzZQovU01hc2sgL05vbmU+PgplbmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iagpbL1BhdHRlcm4gL0Rl&#xd;
```

I'm assuming this is what is causing an issue? Is there a way to convert the response to a single String that can be decoded?

**EDIT 2:**

So the `&#xd;` in the response is definitely my problem. I looked up the [hex code character](http://www.codetable.net/hex/d) and it translates to a carriage return. If I manually copy the **Response** from within JMeter, paste it into Notepad++, remove `&#xd;` and then decode it manually, the PDF opens as it should.

I tried modifying my BeanShell script to remove the carriage return and then decode it, but it still isn't fully functional. The PDF now opens, however, it is just blank white pages. Here is my updated code:

```
String Createresponse= vars.get("documentText");
String b64 = Createresponse.replace("&#xd;","");
vars.put("response",new String(Base64.decodeBase64(b64)));

Output = vars.get("response");

f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Test.pdf");
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Output);
f.close();
```

Comment: Can you check what is the pdf response in View Results Tree? You can refer this article on how to read. https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-read-a-pdf-file-in-apache-jmeter

Comment: Decode should use a String. getBytes("UTF-8") may return something wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of what the first several lines of the PDF response looks like

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You input data is wrong.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestBase64 {

    String data = 
"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8pCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAo/v8AUQB0ACAANQAuADUALgAxKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTcwMzI3MTgwNTEzKQo+Pgpl";
@Test
    public void decodeBase64()
    {
        byte[] localData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/testout64.dat"))
        {
            out.write(localData);

            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This results in

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ)
/Creator (þÿ)
/Producer (þÿ Q t   5 . 5 . 1)
/CreationDate (D:20170327180513)
>>
e
```

and seems to be valid PDF.
What is the &_#_x_d_;_ part? Seems to be some custom format characters.

Comment: This code does not work for me within JMeter. I have tried to manipulate it a bit but no luck so far. My original code appears to be working fine and the problem is the way the PDF is formatted in the API Response

Comment: I did not setup JMeter. Try to flush "p" before close "f". You may close the file output stream before all data from the print stream may be send. BTW.: Your variable naming does not match any java style guide.

Comment: This is not my original code. I am just trying to get it working and then I will go back and refactor it for sure. Flushing p before closing f had no affect on my outcome, btw. Thanks for the suggestion though. I will still probably keep that in the final version

Answer (score 0):

I basically had the answer to my question, the problem was with the base64 encoded Response I was trying to decode was multi-line and included carriage return hex code.

My solution to this was to remove the carriage return hex code from the response and condense it to a single string of base64 encoded text and then write the file out.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String response = vars.get("documentText");
String encodedFile = response.replace("&#xd;","").replaceAll("[\n]+","");

// Decode the response
vars.put("decodedFile",new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedFile)));

// Write out the decoded file
Output = vars.get("decodedFile");
file = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\decodedFile.pdf");
p = new PrintStream(file); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Output);
p.flush();
file.close();
```